# How to make this more efficient?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

```
Private Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
    txtAnswer.AppendText(1)
End Sub
```

So this is my code (It's for 0 through to 9 and a dot for decimal points).

I'm working on calculator for an assignment, my question is, can I make this more efficient so I don't have a lot code doing the same thing?

I had considered setting up a function to read the contents of the buttons and add them to the textbox, but then the operation buttons and clear buttons would just add to the textbox instead of performing the code assigned to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create one method for the numeric buttons and add their value to the Tag Object.  Then you can just reference the tag object to append to the text

```
Private Sub NumericButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim btn As Button
    btn = sender
    txtAnswer.AppendText(btn.Tag)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `Tag` and not `Text`?

Comment: why text and not Tag...one half dozen or the other.  There are multiple ways to do this.    I picked tag as what if the author had the text One, Two ect... with out knowing this seemed the best approach.

Comment: I guess the button with the number 1 will have a `1` in its `Text` property, that's why I think it's better that way. Otherwise, he will have to repeat the text in the `Tag` property. I have never seen a calculator with the numbers spelled. :P

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I tried doing this but I went wrong somewhere. You was right, I didn't know about Tag. I will look into when to use it properly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function just like that, but it should read the number from the sender's `Text` property, and only assign the number buttons to that function in the `OnClick` event.

The other buttons will have their own `OnClick` methods, and you should make a generic function like in this case when you find a common behavior in some of them. Perhaps you could do another generic function for all `+` `-` `/` `x` operators, it that's appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, I originally thought this would work but I couldn't get it to work, but I can see my mistake with the comment from Sorceri. Also, thanks for the tip on the operators too, I will work that out. Thank you :)

Comment: If the number is in the Text, you can use that property without a problem in my opinion.

Comment: What did you end up using, @ChrisMellor?

Comment: I did use Text just because Tag seemed to want some extra code. Like setting up what each Tag wanted? So I did Sorceri's but just changed Tag to Text.

Comment: Or what I said, actually. ;)